# Different Value of left shift in Go and C#

Tags: c#, go, bit-shift

Below is the left shift code in c# netcore 3.1 and go 1.19.

**C#**

```
var cShartLeftShift = 0x2555C6 << 0x10;
Console.WriteLine(cShartLeftShift);

Output: 1439039488
```

**Go**

```
gLeftShift := 0x2555C6 << 0x10
fmt.Println(gLeftShift)

Output: 160352829440
```

Why and how to match Go output with C# output?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Output the values as hex and you should be able to see what's going on

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jP9bl.png

Comment: `var cShartLeftShift = 0x2555C6L << 0x10;` will produce the correct result. You might want to be more explicit with `long cShartLeftShift = 0x2555C6L << 0x10;` though.